# Are there any sites/services/scripts that will reverse JS minification?

Tags: javascript, minify

I'm looking for a way to input a minified JavaScript file and end up with something readable. I understand that it won't have the original variables, they'll all be single letters, but at least it would have lines breaks and possibly tabs.

Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://elfz.laacz.lv/beautify/. It'll indent and space out everything in your code fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Pretty Diff tool.  It can minify and beautify code without loss of integrity.

http://prettydiff.com/